# How to set selected view in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

Hi it may be a simple suggestion, but its great for me. Actually i tried to set selected value through inline code. if the list items are int(1,2,..) it is working but if i use char(A,B,..) it shows "invalid because it does not exist in the list of items".

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SinterLottype" SortExpression="SinterLottype">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSntrtyp" runat="server" DataValueField="SinterLottype"  SelectedValue ='<%# Bind("SinterLottype") %>'  >
                        <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Is there any conversion required on selectedvalue code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi After loosing some hair i found data specification mismatch in sql and inline code.
i made same data specification like char everywhere, it solved the problem. The error it throws is misguiding us.